# ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage — Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs When upload my react native app

Tags: ios, react-native, testflight

I tried to upload the app to the App Store, but there was a problem. I received an email telling me not to use UIWebView and was rejected.

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs starting from April 2020 . See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using react-native version 0.60+, and add useWebKit={true} prop to your webview component.

If you are not using webview anywhere in your app, this could be because of some dependency code that uses UIWebView. Simply search for UIWebView inside XCode search and update all the pods / libraries that are using UIWebView